# Is this a reasonable data structure to store Controllers?

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures

I think the code is quite self explanatory, but essentially I want to store BoxControllers in my DiagramController so that they can be moved/removed/edited. The DiagramController is essentially the parent of the BoxControllers. Every BoxController has a reference to one Box.

The Box class is comparable with other Boxes by comparing their UIDs, which may be a better key for the Map than the Box itself.

I am not looking for advice on anything other than the way I am storing my BoxControllers; in a Map<Box, BoxController>. However if you have other advice I'm happy to hear it.

```
public class DiagramController {

    private final Map<Box, BoxController> boxControllers = new TreeMap<>();

    DiagramController(Diagram diagram) {
        diagram.boxRemovedObservable.subscribe(boxControllers::remove);
        diagram.boxAddedObservable.subscribe((box) -> boxControllers.put(box, new BoxController(box)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does every box relate to one `BoxController`?

Comment: Yes. I updated my question with that info now.

Comment: @dan1st is my question reasonable, or is there some other problem with my code or question that makes it difficult to answer? I'm not in a hurry to have an answer, just checking to see if I can help out.

Comment: I personally see no problem with using a `Map` like you do in that situation.